# Access kubernetes ingress controller application to the internet using public ip provided

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I study kubernetes ingress-nginx controller and it works fine to me but I want to access it to the internet using a public ip. Our institution given us a public ip where we can setup our servers to it. There is no cloud; this is a physical server where you can access it to the internet and this is where I want to deploy my kubernetes ingress application.

`>As if this is the public ip: 119.92.169.227`

What I want to is that the user can access this public ip and it maps to the kubernetes ingress application.

`http://119.92.169.227/`

minikube generates its own ip address like it acts as a different machine. I try to search to the internet about it but it gives me cloud service configuration, but in my case I don't have a cloud service. I only have a public ip issued by our internet service provider to the institution where I'm at to. Thank you so much for your time if you have any ideas please teach me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using metallb as a load-balancer
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/
MetalLB provides a network load-balancer implementation for Kubernetes clusters that do not run on a supported cloud provider, effectively allowing the usage of LoadBalancer Services within any cluster.

Comment: I try using it but the ingress-nginx external ip stuck on pending.

Comment: Try using minikube tunnel Reference link https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#using-minikube-tunnel